# Vbscript explanation

Tags: vbscript

What do these two constants mean

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393866.aspx

Comment: those two constants are numbers in hexadecimal form `&h` is used to tell the parser that the numbers after it, is in hexadecimal (base 16), not decimal (base 10). `&h10` equals 16, `&h20` equals 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Vista Windows Software Development Kit
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Value Meaning

wbemFlagForwardOnly

32 0x20 Causes a forward-only enumerator to be returned. Forward-only enumerators are generally much faster and use less memory than conventional enumerators, but they do not allow calls to SWbemObject.Clone_.

wbemFlagBidirectional

0 0x0 Causes WMI to retain pointers to objects of the enumeration until the client releases the enumerator.

wbemFlagReturnImmediately

16 0x10 Causes the call to return immediately.

wbemFlagReturnWhenComplete

0 0x0 Causes this call to block until the query is complete. This flag calls the method in the synchronous mode.

wbemQueryFlagPrototype

2 0x2 Used for prototyping. It stops the query from happening and returns an object that looks like a typical result object.

wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers

131072 0x20000 Causes WMI to return class amendment data with the base class definition. For more information, see Localizing WMI Class Information.

Comment: I'm not a programmer I'm just doing this too make my application faster.